# RabbitMQ C# Client - can producer receive event when consumer acknowledges the message

Tags: c#, notifications, rabbitmq, consumer

Is it possible to configure RabbitMQ so that when the consumer manually acks a message the consumer is informed.

I am using the C# RabbitMQ client. I have set up my model/channel as ConsumeSelect, however I receive the BasicAcks event before the message is consumed by the consumer. I'm assuming this being acked when it has been routed to a queue.

I want to be able to receive the event when the message has been acked by the consumer.

My exchange and queue are set up as follows

```
model.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "myExchange", type: "topic");
                model.QueueDeclare(queue: "myQueue", durable: false,
                                        exclusive: false,
                                        autoDelete: false,
                                        arguments: null);
                model.QueueBind(queue: "myQueue",
                    exchange: "myExchange",
                    routingKey: "myRoutingKey");
```

The producer is set up as follows

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
{

    HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitHost"],
    UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitUserName"],
    Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitPassword"],
    Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitPort"]),
};
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
var model = connection.CreateModel();
model.ConfirmSelect();
model.CallbackException += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception [{0}] [{1}] [{2}]", e.Detail, e.Exception.Message, e.Exception.StackTrace);
};

model.BasicReturn += (s, e) =>
{
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Body);
    Console.WriteLine("Message returned [{0}] [{1}] [{2}]", message, e.ReplyCode, e.ReplyText);
};

model.BasicAcks += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message acked [delivery tag = {0}] [multiple = {1}]", e.DeliveryTag, e.Multiple);
};
```

My message is sent in the following way

```
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "myExchange",
                    routingKey: "myRoutingKey",
                    mandatory: true,
                    basicProperties: null,
                    body: "my message");
```

Comment: You might want to read into https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html

Comment: The caveats say that we have to use auto-acknowledgement, which is not an option for us. My real goal is to ensure I do not lose messages. I've realised that even using clusters, mirrored queues and persistent messages, it is still possible to lose messages in RabbitMQ. So I am now investigating the scenario where, I can lose a message but I can detect that it has been lost. I this case I would detect it has been lost as I would not have received an ack. However this only works if I receive the consumers ack and not a ack to say it has been added to a queue successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I now understand I could achieve the goal of not losing messages, it wasn't obvious to me at first.

If the following is configured

Messages are persistant
The queue is durable
Consumer acknowledgments are enabled

This ensures that the producer will receive an event when the master and all mirrored queues have accepted the message, this ensures the data has been persisted to disk. This ensures that they are in sync.

The only problem with this is that if you had your master and mirrors going down and being restored in quick succession, then messages could still be lost